# PL SQL stored procedure to copy rows in the same table with modified data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle10g, block

I am new to PL-SQL dialect. At work, I am using an old Oracle 10g DBMS, I need to select some rows from a table here called "myWorkTable", to modify some fields for each selected row and finally to insert the new rows in the same table.
In the past I did something similar with T-SQL but PL-SQL doesn't allow DDL (like CREATE and DROP) inside a block or procedure so it doesn't work. To give you an idea of what I would like to accomplish, below is my not working code in PL SQL:

```
DECLARE

  old VARCHAR2( 31 ) := 'oldString';
  new VARCHAR2( 31 ) := 'newString';
 
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE myDB.tmp1 AS SELECT * FROM myDB.myWorkTable where myField = old;
    UPDATE myDB.tmp1 SET myField = new;
    INSERT INTO myDB.myWorkTable SELECT * FROM myDB.tmp1;
    DROP TABLE myDB.tmp1;

END;
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same result not using DDL inside the PL-SQL a block or a stored procedure? Thanks for your hints & tips!

Answer (score 2):

You could just list all the columns:

```
INSERT INTO myDB.myWorkTable
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'new' as myField, . . ..
    FROM myDB.tmp1;
```

Then you don't have to fiddle with temporary tables.

Comment: Do you mean like below, without myDB.tmp1? 

    INSERT INTO myDB.myWorkTable 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'new' as myField, . . .. 
    FROM myDB.myWorkTable;

Comment: @Mike . . . Basically yes.